# .NET Core Partial View Turkish Character Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, partial-views, asp.net-mvc-partialview, asp.net-core-1.0

I'm new in `.net Core`. And i have a problem on `Partial View`'s for Turkish characters.

I have a `CssController` and it has `Tipografi.cshtml`, `Button.cshtml`, etc.

There is my codes and pictures:

```
@{
if (ViewContext.ActionDescriptor.DisplayName.ToString().IndexOf("Css") != -1)
{
    <div class="col-md-3 text-center" style="background-color:lavender;">
        <div class="panel-heading" align="left"><h3>İç Menü</h3></div>
        <div class="list-group">
            <a class="list-group-item @((ViewContext.ActionDescriptor.DisplayName.ToString().IndexOf("Tipografi") != -1) ? "active" : "")" asp-controller="Css" asp-action="Tipografi">Tipografi</a>
            <a class="list-group-item @((ViewContext.ActionDescriptor.DisplayName.ToString().IndexOf("Tablolar") != -1) ? "active" : "")" asp-controller="Css" asp-action="Tablolar">Tablolar</a>
            <a class="list-group-item @((ViewContext.ActionDescriptor.DisplayName.ToString().IndexOf("Code") != -1) ? "active" : "")" asp-controller="Css" asp-action="Code">Code</a>
            <a class="list-group-item @((ViewContext.ActionDescriptor.DisplayName.ToString().IndexOf("Form") != -1) ? "active" : "")" asp-controller="Css" asp-action="Form">Form</a>
            <a class="list-group-item @((ViewContext.ActionDescriptor.DisplayName.ToString().IndexOf("Button") != -1) ? "active" : "")" asp-controller="Css" asp-action="Button">Button</a>
            <a class="list-group-item @((ViewContext.ActionDescriptor.DisplayName.ToString().IndexOf("Image") != -1) ? "active" : "")" asp-controller="Css" asp-action="Image">Image</a>
            <a class="list-group-item @((ViewContext.ActionDescriptor.DisplayName.ToString().IndexOf("Yardimcilar") != -1) ? "active" : "")" asp-controller="Css" asp-action="Yardimcilar">Yardımcılar</a>
        </div><p>üğçöıİ</p>
    </div>
}
else
{

    <div class="col-md-3 text-center" style="background-color:lavender;">
        <div class="panel-heading" align="left"><h3>Hizmetler</h3></div>
        <div class="list-group">
            There is a list
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

}

It's working but characters look like [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgmHo.png).

There is my Layout Code:

```
<body>
@Html.Partial("MasterPage//Header.cshtml")
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3" style="background-color:lavender;margin-bottom:30px;">
        @Html.Partial("MasterPage//Duyurular.cshtml")

        @Html.Partial("MasterPage//Etkinlikler.cshtml")

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6" style="background-color:lavenderblush;padding-bottom:20px;padding-top:20px;">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
    @Html.Partial("MasterPage//Hizmetler")
</div>


@Html.Partial("MasterPage//Footer.cshtml")

There is some scripst and others...

@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem. I created a new view and copied code from other page..